# Disable gnome-keyring-daemon

Tags: debian, gpg, thunderbird, gnome-keyring, enigmail

Methods I have tried:

- https://wiki.gnupg.org/GnomeKeyring
- https://blog.josefsson.org/tag/keyring/
- Removing the GNOME Keyring applications from Startup Applications
- http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/installation/#disable-ssh-component-of-gnome-keyring

None of these stop this process from being started when I log in:

```
me       1865  0.0  0.0 281816  7104 ?        Sl   10:50   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

This stops my Thunderbird from decrypting emails properly. When I kill the process, I can decrypt emails as expected but I don't want to have to do that every time I log in.

```
OS Information: Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could try removing the `gnome-keyring` package.

Comment: **This is dangerous advice.** Unfortunately, on many GNU/Linux distributions, using your package manager to remove the `gnome-keyring` package **will also remove the `gnome` package and numerous others.** (In an ideal world, removing the `gnome-keyring` package would indeed be the right answer, but in the real world, unless you want to uninstall your whole desktop environment, you should evaluate other solutions.)

Answer (score 13):

Actually the gnome-keyring-daemon in several cases is started via X login using the PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) files, but there is other ways like autostart files too [GnomeKeyring/RunningDaemon](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/RunningDaemon). You can look in detail about the integration of PAM on [official documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam). But in general you just need to detect which desktop manager are you using and delete the entries on your `/etc/pam.d/<desktop_manager>`.

In my case, I use the `lightdm`. So I have a PAM file called `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` which has that contents:

```
❯ cat /etc/pam.d/lightdm
#%PAM-1.0
auth        include     system-login
-auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
account     include     system-login
password    include     system-login
session     include     system-login
-session    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

Deleting or comment the entries which call the `pam_gnome_keyring.so` module, located on `/lib/security`, you can accomplish the full disable of the daemon on login. To be sure, look to `/etc/xdg/autostart` and `~/.config/autostart` for files with the pattern `gnome-keyring-*.desktop` and append `Hidden=true` on each file to disable that component as well.

#### How To on antiX 17.1 (based on Debian 'stretch')

**NOTE:** This, or something close to it, should work for most Debian-based systems.

- For each user for which `gnome-keyring-daemon` should not start on login...

  - For each service for which there is a file like...

    ```
    /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-*.desktop
    ```
  - Create a file of the exact same name in:  `~/.config/autostart`

    - Containing only...

      ```
      [Desktop Entry]
      Hidden=true
      ```
    - Such as...

      ```
      ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop
      ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop
      ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
      ```
    - Insure that each file is owned by their respective user and has permissions 644 (rw-r--r--)
  - OPTIONAL: Disable `gnome-keyring-daemon` processes for 'login'

    - The above per-user changes still allow 1 or 2 `gnome-keyring-daemon` processes to be started at login. But they will automatically stop after a couple of minutes if no per-user processes are started. Thus, alteration of these `/etc/pam.d` files is not really necessary but is provided for completeness.

      - Comment out `gnome-keyring-daemon` lines in the PAM config file for the display manager (antiX uses `slim`):  `/etc/pam.d/slim`

        ```
        # auth      optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so
        # session   optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
        ```
      - Comment out gnome-keyring-daemon lines in the PAM config file:  */etc/pam.d/common-password*

        ```
        # password  optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so
        ```
  - Reboot

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. Thanks. 
I use so I've commented the lines in the files /etc/pam.d/gdm-*

Comment: Great to know that works for you too, @KevinLemaire!

Answer (score 6):

For simple disabling (rather than removing), how about removing execute permission? (You will need appropriate permissions, so you may need to prefix `sudo`).

```
$ chmod -x $(type -p gnome-keyring-daemon)
```

You could also kill the process if its currently running:

```
$ pkill gnome-keyring-daemon
```

Comment: Technically that is correct, but pretty horrible.  You will end with errors poping up in journalctl and/or syslog.  Also, you need root to perform those commands (that would be wise to mention in the answer)

Comment: Very fair point. However I would add that there will only be a few log lines---not enough to cause problems by drowning out real logged events---so you may be willing to accept this cost at least until a more elegant solution is found. (edited answer to reflect need for permissions)

Comment: This is the only solution that helped in my case, Debian Bullseye. I tried disabling the daemon in the configuration files as proposed in the other answer, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Monitor, in processes tab scroll down and select `gnome-keyring-daemon`,  and click end process.

I'm using Kali GNU/Linux Rolling and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to keep it on your hard drive for some reason? If not `sudo apt-get remove gnome-keyring` seems like the obvious solution (and solved the problem I had with it, with no evident harmful side effects).

Comment: This sounds good in theory, but in practice, if your desktop package `Depends` on it, you may end up removing your desktop package.  Yes, it should be `Recommends` instead, but... package quality varies.